# JFrog Artifactory doesn't request user/password when deploying

Tags: maven, artifactory, maven-deploy-plugin

We have setup Artifactory using the Google Cloud Click to deploy.

I have added the settings.xml file:

```
<servers>
  <server>
    <username>deployer</username>
    <password>hello</password>
    <id>company-central</id>
  </server>
</servers>
```

I have added the following to the pom.xml:

```
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>company-central</id>
        <name>company-central</name>
        <url>http://ourURL/artifactory/libs-release-local</url>
    </repository>
</distributionManagement>
```

When I run **mvn deploy** I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project auth0test:
Failed to deploy artifacts: ... Return code is: 401, ReasonPhrase: Unauthorized. -> [Help 1]
```

Looking at the artifactory logs, the request is coming in as anonymous:

2016-11-08 11:40:49,035 [DENIED DEPLOY] libs-release-local:/auth0test-1.0.jar for anonymous/.

There is no subsequent request to authenticate with the 'deployer' user.  Artifactory has anonymous access disabled and the anonymous user has had all its permissions removed.

When forcing credentials from the command line, this works:

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file 
-Durl=http://deployer:hello@ourURL/artifactory/libs-release-local 
-DpomFile=pom.xml 
-DrepositoryId=company-central 
-Dfile=target/auth0test-1.0.jar
```

Is this an error with Artifactory or with Maven?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maven's first request is indeed anonymous, this is a common practice done for security reasons - not disclosing your credentials to the server if not needed to.

At this point Artifactory identifies that this is an anonymous request and that there are insufficient permissions and therefor returns a 401 status.

When receiving the 401, Maven should respond to the challenge and resend the request with the proper credentials. This is the step that I assume is not working properly.
Running Maven with a debug information might reveal more details.